# 3-way interaction in plot_model

Tags: r, regression, visualization, interaction

I have fit a mixed-effects model and included a 3-way interaction between my fixed effects which are:
two categorical variables: A1(level1, level2), A2 (level1, level2)
continuous: B

```
model <- lmer( dependent variable~ A1*A2 * B + random factors, data)
```

To visualise the interaction, I am using `plot_model` from the "sjPlot" package:

```
plot_model(model, type="int", terms=c("A1", "A2", "B"))
```

The output seems to have broken down my continuous variable (B) into two separate categories (high B, low B) and then plot the interaction for each of the categories in two separate windows.
My question is:

What criterion does the "sjPlot" package use to categorise my continuous variable? What determines "high B" and what determines "low B"? And I wonder if there is any other way to visualise a three-way interaction which is more informative.

Thank you!

Comment: I suspect that this is controlled by the `mdrt.values` argument, but I'm not sure. Is there any chance you could post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 2):

welcome to SO. I use sjPlot quite a bit and took this opportunity to consolidate some of my knowledge about it.

There is also the fact that calling `plot_model(..., type = "int)` will use the order of the variables in the regression formula to decide how to plot that interaction. Here I've drawn up an example using the 'mtcars' data-set included in R. I transform two of the binary variables into factors first so it matches your example.

```
library(sjPlot)

mtcars$vs <- as.factor(as.character(mtcars$vs))
mtcars$am <- as.factor(as.character(mtcars$am))

m1 <- lm(mpg ~ vs * am * hp,
         data = mtcars)

plot_model(m1,
           type = "int")
```

This code produces the following plot, where two values of the continuous variable `hp` have been selected for plotting in two separate windows:

[image]

Ben is correct, and these values are pulled from the `mdrt.values` argument, which defaults to "minmax", meaning these values should be the highest and lowest in that column, which we can verify:

```
range(mtcars$hp)
[1]  52 335
```

There are other options for this argument, some of which will be better or worse depending on your case. As you only have one continuous variable, we might want to show the whole predictor along the x-axis. We can do this in a few ways, one of which is changing the model formula so that `hp` is first.

```
m2 <- lm(mpg ~ hp * vs * am,
         data = mtcars)

plot_model(m2,
           type = "int")
```

[image]

However, this is probably not the best way to do this, as sometimes models take a while to fit and re-fitting the model for plotting is a waste of time/electricity. It's useful to know here that the `type = "int"` call is just for convenience, and that we can also plot interactions by setting `type="pred"` and then passing the effects we want to be plotted using the `terms` argument. Thefollowing code will make a very similar plot to the second one, but using the first model that we fit. Changing the order of the terms included within `c()` will change the plot.

```
plot_model(m1,
           type = "pred",
           terms = c("hp", "vs", "am"))
```